# I fried an ESP8266 Wemos Mini with a simple circuit, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: voltage-regulator, esp8266

I'm pretty new to electronics, I'm more of a computer guy.

I followed [this](https://www.electroniclinic.com/wireless-vibration-sensor-iot-vibration-sensor-industrial-vibration-sensor-nodemcu-esp8266/) tutorial to build a vibration sensor. My circuit looks like below.

When I turned it on everything worked, but within a few minutes I noticed a burning smell and my microcontroller stopped working ever since. I suspect I fried the onboard voltage regulator. I tried providing 3.3V to 3.3V pin, now the ESP8266 module is heating up.

I am afraid to use a new microcontroller to fry it again with the same circuit.

What am I doing wrong? I checked for a short circuit, my soldering looks okay. Do I need a resistor to D0 of SW420?

[image]

Comment: +/- 5V?  that means you effectively connected 10V to the 5V input... ya that would do it. Did you measure the input voltage 5V to Gnd at the module? Or is it just an oddly labeled schematic?

Comment: maybe something weird happened with the buck converter, since it requires 18 V between the input pins and you supplied only 9 V

Comment: Did you measure the buck converter output **before** you connected to the ESP8266 module? It should be 0V (not -5V) and +5V for G and +5 inputs respectively.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your comments. My schema was wrong in my original question, I edited with the correct one here. @ChrisStratton: Yes, my board is not actual ESP8266, it's Wemos D1 mini. I measured the Buck convertor output, the output is 5V to the ground.

Comment: @tlfong01 please stop cluttering the page with irrelevant comments, this ongoing habit of yours across many questions is quite problematic and needs to stop

Comment: @ramesh, I skimmed your tutorials and datasheet. The tutorial is good. I made a picture summary for reference in our discussions later:https://i.imgur.com/0tU4OVZ.jpeg. My first impression is that the wiring and everything else looks OK.

Comment: @ramesh, it would be nice if you can show me a photo of your setup, and which IDE you are using, though I think that it is unlikely that IDE would not cause any trouble.

Comment: Before I go, I forgot yo tell you that the SW420 vibration/shake sensor wiring also looks  OK. I also need to read my old posts to see if there is anything need to take precaution when playing with shake sensors. I only remember the problems are about sensitivity/resolution.Here is one of a couple of old posts I found so far: Shake and Vibration Sensors - rpi.org.forum 2020jan12,
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/107191/how-to-manually-control-a-shake-activated-lamp-using-raspberry-pi. cheers.

Comment: @ramesh, in the above vibration sensor post I referred, the sensor is actually connected to some power electronics at 220VAC. That is why I hope to see your hardware setup, just to make sure that no higher voltage source is connected.

Comment: Check the Voutput of the buckconverter with an oscilloscope if you have one. If not, try disconnecting the sw-420 and see if the wemos heats up. If it doesn't, connect the voltage line to the sw-420 and check again. This requires putting a board on the line. I can't tell what the problem is without seeing how the output of the converter looks like since it seems all okay to me.

Comment: Have you configured pin D0 as an input in the software? If D0 is inadvertently set as an output there could be an issue where the SW420 signal is shorted.

Comment: @ramesh, I vaguely remember when I first tested ESP8266-12, I used Win10/RealTerm/PowerShell and Rpi Cutecom to talk to ESP. If you started off with ESP 3V3 Tx/Rx connected to any 5V Tx/Rx, you might be in trouble. But I am a bit confused. A photo and schematic showing ESP8266 Tx/Rx connecting to which MCU/SBC/PC would be helpful.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, it looks everything works okay when I provide power via microusb, but not via 5V input pin.